# laravel how to get the retry event in the Job?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I use redis to store the number of unprocessed queued jobs for each user.

In the controller, increment the jobNumber by 1 when dispatch a job for the user.

```
Job::dispatch($job);
$redis->SET( $uid, $redis->GET($uid) + 1);
```

In the Job's `handle()` function decrement the jobNumber by 1 when a job begin processing. And rollback when the Job failed.

```
public function handle()
{
    ...
    $redis->SET( $uid, $redis->GET($uid) - 1);
    ...
}
public function failed(\Exception $exception)
{
    ...
    $redis->SET( $uid, $redis->GET($uid) + 1);
    \Log::info('job failed');
}
```

This work well when the job can finish in the first time. But when a job fail in the first time and retry the number in the redis will decrease by 1 which shouldn't.

Note the `failed` function only called when the job thoroughly failed, will not been called when retry. If there is a `retried` function like the `failed` would be better.

So how can I catch the queue retry event in the Job.

Comment: maybe you can put -1 into the last line of code of handle, or in cases that really success, so -1 won't be called many times when handle() being called? actually i see an event JobExceptionOccurred in souce code, maybe that event can do the trick too. https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.5/src/Illuminate/Queue/Events. i didn't test that yet

Comment: Smart guy, it's a workaround. Thank you.